# Emulate Python's random.choice in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, random

Python's module 'random' has a function [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice)

> **`random.choice(seq)`**
>   Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If `seq` is empty, raises `IndexError`.

How can I emulate this in .NET ?

```
public T RandomChoice<T> (IEnumerable<T> source)
```

---

Edit: I heard this as an interview question some years ago, but today the problem occurred naturally in my work. The interview question was stated with constraints

- 'the sequence is too long to save to memory'
- 'you can only loop over the sequence once'
- 'the sequence doesn't have a length/count method' (à la .NET IEnumerable)

Comment: Are you saying you want a function which would return you *exactly what Python does*? Or you want a function with *the same contract*? That is, would you be happy if the .NET function returned different elements from what Python would?

Comment: Just to comment on the answers provided, @MattHickford, perhaps you should consider, in addition to an `IEnumerable` include an `IList` overload (or do a check in the `IEnumerable` if it's an `IList`) so you can avoid having to enumerate and create a copied collection.  EDIT: You could also add a `params` overload to pull out a list made at compile time: `RandomChoice("apple", "pear", "orange")`

Comment: AakashM, I ask for a .NET analogue of the Python function. What's a contract?

Comment: Oh, our difficulty communicating is that the English words 'emulate', 'analogue' and 'contract' are overloaded with precise technical meanings. I'm using the dictionary definitions. And by dictionary, I   don't mean the data structure!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make a method that iterates the source only once, and doesn't have to allocate memory to store it temporarily, you count how many items you have iterated, and determine the probability that the current item should be the result:

```
public T RandomChoice<T> (IEnumerable<T> source) {
  Random rnd = new Random();
  T result = default(T);
  int cnt = 0;
  foreach (T item in source) {
    cnt++;
    if (rnd.Next(cnt) == 0) {
      result = item;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

When you are at the first item, the probability is 1/1 that it should be used (as that is the only item that you have seen this far). When you are at the second item, the probability is 1/2 that it should replace the first item, and so on.

---

This will naturally use a bit more CPU, as it creates one random number per item, not just a single random number to select an item, as dasblinkenlight pointed out. You can check if the source implements `IList<T>`, as Dan Tao suggested, and use an implementation that uses the capabilities to get the length of the collection and access items by index:

```
public T RandomChoice<T> (IEnumerable<T> source) {
  IList<T> list = source as IList<T>;
  if (list != null) {
    // use list.Count and list[] to pick an item by random
  } else {
    // use implementation above
  }
}
```

Note: You should consider sending the `Random` instance into the method. Otherwise you will get the same random seed if you call the method two times too close in time, as the seed is created from the current time.

---

The result of a test run, picking one number from an array containing 0 - 9, 1000000 times, to show that the distribution of the chosen numbers is not skewed:

```
0: 100278
1: 99519
2: 99994
3: 100327
4: 99571
5: 99731
6: 100031
7: 100429
8: 99482
9: 100638
```

Comment: Ah, nice. I remember having to do something like this once! The thing is, I think you'll need to show the math to convince all readers this is correct (it's not immediately intuitive that it's correct—at least to me).

Comment: I would also suggest still optimizing for the case where `source` is an `IList<T>`, as it will obviously be faster to access a single element randomly by index than to iterate over the list if you don't have to.

Comment: +1 Very nice! Here is a [link to a simple proof by induction](http://propersubset.com/2010/04/choosing-random-elements.html) that this algorithm picks a random element with the probability of `1/N`. You may want to note that this algorithm saves memory for the temp variable at the expense of using additional CPU to generate `N` random numbers instead of a single one. It does not matter with the regular RNG, but using a cryptographically strong one may turn this into a tradeoff.

Comment: IMO the passing the instance of `Random` should be part of your actual code, and not just a note several paragraphs later.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Even crypto PRNGs are pretty fast. Some are below 8 cpb, and even the relatively slow RNGCryptoServiceProvider is at 40 cpb.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes, perhaps. I wanted to show a method that had the exact signature as in the question.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid iterating through the sequence two times (once for the count and once for the element) it is probably a good idea to save your sequence in an array before getting its random element:

```
public static class RandomExt {
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static T RandomChoice<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source) {
        var arr = source.ToArray();   
        return arr[rnd.Next(arr.Length)];
    }
    public static T RandomChoice<T> (this ICollection<T> source) {
        return source[rnd.Next(rnd.Count)];
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Implemented a [very good idea by Chris Sinclair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314908/emulate-pythons-random-choice-in-net/11314962#comment14891681_11314908).

Comment: I especially like this as an extension method. +1

Comment: Why `IList<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: this Violates the Constraint 'the sequence is too long to save to memory' though I notice that you probably answered before the constraint was added...

Comment: @AmitMittal This constraint wasn't there when I answered the question.

Comment: ahh...just when I was editing the comment after noticing that :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, @CodeInChaos: I said `IList` because `ICollection` doesn't have the indexer `[index]` notation. So your edited code won't compile anymore. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
private static Random rng = new Random();

...
return source.Skip(rng.next(source.Count())).Take(1);
```

Comment: 1) Don't forget the locking. 2) Your code requires multiple enumerations of a sequence, which should generally be avoided. 3) `Take(1)` returns a single element sequence. You should use `First()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
        public T RandomChoice<T> (IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
            }

            var list = source.ToList();

            if (list.Count < 1)
            {
                throw new MissingMemberException();
            }

            var rnd = new Random();
            return list[rnd.Next(0, list.Count)];
        }
```

or extension

```
    public static T RandomChoice<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        var list = source.ToList();

        if (list.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new MissingMemberException();
        }

        var rnd = new Random();
        return list[rnd.Next(0, list.Count)];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314962/105570), with one small change: leverage the fact that `source` might already be an indexed collection, in which case you really don't need to populate a new array (or list):

```
public static class RandomExt
{
    public static T Choice<T>(this Random random, IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        var list = sequence as IList<T> ?? sequence.ToList();
        return list[random.Next(list.Count)];
    }
}
```

Note that I also modified the interface from the abovementioned answer to make it more consistent with the Python version you referenced in your question:

```
var random = new Random();
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int randomNumber = random.Choice(numbers);
```

**Edit**: I like [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315054/105570) even better, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, get a list of all elements in the sequence. ask a random number generator for the index, return elemnt by index. Define what Sequence is - IEnumerable would be most obvious, but you need to materialize that into a list then to know the number of elements for the random number generator.
This is btw., not emulate, it is implement.

Is this some homework beginner study course question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one has an extension method `IEnumerable.MinBy`:

```
var r = new Random();
return source.MinBy(x=>r.Next())
```

The method `MinBy` doesn't save the sequence to memory, it works like `IEnumerable.Min` making one iteration (see [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) or [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326714/284795) )

Comment: This is not much different than what @dasblinkenlight has suggested. This also involves creating a number of random numbers and then deciding when to terminate (though checks are different in both the cases).