# C# test if variable assigned

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to code a Linq MinBy extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T MinBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,int> selector)
    {
        T min;
        int? minKey = null;
        foreach (var x in source)
        {
            var key = selector(x);
            if (minKey == null || key < minKey)
            {
                minKey = key;
                min = x;
            }
        }
        if (minKey == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("source should not be empty");
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

I think my logic is correct and readable. But I get a build error

> Use of unassigned local variable 'min'

What can I do about this? Can I test if the variable is assigned?

---

Clarification: A MinBy function can answer the following question. Which of the numbers [-5, -2, 3] has the smallest square?

```
> new List<int>{-5,-2,3}.MinBy(x => x*x)
-2
```

.NET's Min function answers a different question (which is the smallest of the squares)

```
> new List<int>{-5,-2,3}.Min(x => x*x)
4
```

Comment: IQueryable<> would be even better than IEnumerable<> imho for this.

Comment: Check it out on MSDN, it's a type of collection which allows query chaining, very powerful.

Comment: Can't you use the existing IEnumerable.Min extension method? - this allows you to pass a func<T,int> too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548864

Comment: Good question Toby. I wrote a clarification of the behaviour I want in the original question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a default value for `min` like this:

`T min = default(T);`

[You can read more about `default()` on MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Given a variable t of a parameterized type T, the statement t = null
>   is only valid if T is a reference type and t = 0 will only work for
>   numeric value types but not for structs. The solution is to use the
>   default keyword, which will return null for reference types and zero
>   for numeric value types. For structs, it will return each member of
>   the struct initialized to zero or null depending on whether they are
>   value or reference types. For nullable value types, default returns a
>   System.Nullable, which is initialized like any struct.

Comment: Thanks. Does this break my logic? After a little thought, no.

Answer (score 4):

Add a default value for `min`:

```
T min = default(T);
```

The reason it's complaining is that the compiler cannot verify that `min` will have been assigned a value before it's used in the `return min;` line. An unassigned local variable cannot be referenced, and so the compiler generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

That is because min is assigned inside the condition. Compiler can't determine whether it will get a value or not, you should initialize min with the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) value.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can't test whether a variable is assigned, you will always get a compile error.

Answer (score -1):

FYI this is what I ended up with

```
    public static T MinBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,int> selector)
    {
        T min = default(T);
        bool started = false;
        int minKey = default(int);
        foreach (var x in source)
        {
            var key = selector(x);
            if (!started || key < minKey)
            {
                minKey = key;
                min = x;
                started = true;
            }
        }
        if (!started)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("source should not be empty","source");
        }
        return min;
    }
```