# Python numpy.random.choice in C# with non/uniform probability distribution

Tags: c#, python, numpy, random

I am trying to put into place some code that will do the same as Python, [Numpy.random.Choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

The critical part is: `probability`

> The probabilities associated with each entry in a. If not given the sample assumes a uniform distribution over all entries in a.

Some Test Code:

```
import numpy as np

n = 5

vocab_size = 3

p = np.array( [[ 0.65278451], [ 0.0868038725], [ 0.2604116175]])

print('Sum: ', repr(sum(p)))

for t in range(n):
    x = np.random.choice(range(vocab_size), p=p.ravel())
    print('x: %s x[x]: %s' % (x, p.ravel()[x]))

print(p.ravel())
```

This gives an output of:

```
Sum:  array([ 1.])
x: 0 x[x]: 0.65278451
x: 0 x[x]: 0.65278451
x: 0 x[x]: 0.65278451
x: 0 x[x]: 0.65278451
x: 0 x[x]: 0.65278451
[ 0.65278451  0.08680387  0.26041162]
```

Sometimes.

There is a Distribution here, and it is a partially Random one, but there is also Structure there.

I want to implement this in C#, and to be honest, I am not sure on an efficient way to do it.

Some 4 Years ago there was a good question asked: [Emulate Python's random.choice in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314908/emulate-pythons-random-choice-in-net/11314962#comment14891681_11314908)

Being this is quite old now and also does not really go into depth on the uniform probability distribution, I thought I would ask for some elaboration?

Now times have changed and Code is changing, I think there may be a better way to implement a .NET `Random.Choice()` Method.

```
public static int Choice(Vector sequence, int a = 0, int size = 0, bool replace = false)
{
    // F(x)
    var Fx = 1/(b - a)
    var p = (xmax - xmin) * Fx

    return random.Next(0, sequence.Length);
}
```

Vector is only a double[].

How would I go about randomly Choosing a Probability from a Vector like so:

```
 p = np.array(
 [[ 0.01313731], [ 0.01315883], [ 0.01312814], [ 0.01316345], [ 0.01316839],
 [ 0.01314225], [ 0.01317578], [ 0.01312916], [ 0.01316344], [ 0.01317046],
 [ 0.01314973], [ 0.01314432], [ 0.01317042], [ 0.01314846], [ 0.01315124],
 [ 0.01316694], [ 0.0131816 ], [ 0.01315033], [ 0.0131645 ], [ 0.01314199],
 [ 0.01315199], [ 0.01314431], [ 0.01314458], [ 0.01314999], [ 0.01315409],
 [ 0.01316245], [ 0.01315008], [ 0.01314104], [ 0.01315215], [ 0.01317024],
 [ 0.01315993], [ 0.01318789], [ 0.0131677 ], [ 0.01316761], [ 0.01315658],
 [ 0.01315902], [ 0.01314266], [ 0.0131637 ], [ 0.01315702], [ 0.01315776],
 [ 0.01316194], [ 0.01316246], [ 0.01314769], [ 0.01315608], [ 0.01315487],
 [ 0.01316117], [ 0.01315083], [ 0.01315836], [ 0.0131665 ], [ 0.01314706],
 [ 0.01314923], [ 0.01317971], [ 0.01316373], [ 0.01314863], [ 0.01315498],
 [ 0.01315732], [ 0.01318195], [ 0.01315505], [ 0.01315979], [ 0.01315992],
 [ 0.01316072], [ 0.01314744], [ 0.0131638 ], [ 0.01315642], [ 0.01314933],
 [ 0.01316188], [ 0.01315458], [ 0.01315551], [ 0.01317907], [ 0.01316296],
 [ 0.01317765], [ 0.01316863], [ 0.01316804], [ 0.01314882], [ 0.01316548],
 [ 0.01315487]])
```

The Output in Python is:

```
Sum:  array([ 1.])
x: 21 x[x]: 0.01314431
x: 30 x[x]: 0.01315993
x: 54 x[x]: 0.01315498
x: 31 x[x]: 0.01318789
x: 27 x[x]: 0.01314104
```

Sometimes.

**EDIT:**
After Coffee and sleep, some more insight. The Documentation explains:

> Generate a non-uniform random sample from np.arange(5) of size 3 without replacement:
>
> > np.random.choice(5, 3, replace=False, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])
> >     array([2, 3, 0])

The parameter `p` introduces a Non-Uniform Distribution to the sequence or Choice.

> The probabilities associated with each entry in `a`. If not given the sample assumes a uniform distribution over all entries in `a`.

So I guess, if:

```
static int[] a = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75};



static double[] p = new double[] { 0.01313731,  0.01315883,  0.01312814,  0.01316345,  0.01316839,  0.01314225,
0.01317578,  0.01312916,  0.01316344,  0.01317046,  0.01314973,  0.01314432,
0.01317042,  0.01314846,  0.01315124,  0.01316694,  0.0131816,   0.01315033,
0.0131645,   0.01314199,  0.01315199,  0.01314431,  0.01314458,  0.01314999,
0.01315409,  0.01316245,  0.01315008,  0.01314104,  0.01315215,  0.01317024,
0.01315993,  0.01318789,  0.0131677,   0.01316761,  0.01315658,  0.01315902,
0.01314266,  0.0131637,   0.01315702,  0.01315776,  0.01316194,  0.01316246,
0.01314769,  0.01315608,  0.01315487,  0.01316117,  0.01315083,  0.01315836,
0.0131665,   0.01314706,  0.01314923,  0.01317971,  0.01316373,  0.01314863,
0.01315498,  0.01315732,  0.01318195,  0.01315505,  0.01315979,  0.01315992,
0.01316072,  0.01314744,  0.0131638,   0.01315642,  0.01314933,  0.01316188,
0.01315458,  0.01315551,  0.01317907,  0.01316296,  0.01317765,  0.01316863,
0.01316804,  0.01314882,  0.01316548,  0.01315487 };
```

How would I efficiently calculate this distribution?

**EDIT:**

While the above `p` Parameter may not have a clear distribution:

[image]

This `p` Parameter does:

```
p = np.array(
[[  3.09571694e-03], [  6.62372261e-04], [  2.52917874e-04], [  6.93371978e-04],
[  2.22301291e-04], [  3.53796717e-02], [  2.36204398e-04], [  2.41100042e-04],
[  1.59093166e-02], [  5.17099025e-04], [  2.72037896e-04], [  1.29918769e-03],
[  2.68077696e-02], [  5.68696611e-04], [  5.32142704e-04], [  5.88432463e-05],
[  2.53700138e-02], [  2.51216588e-03], [  4.72895541e-04], [  4.20276848e-03],
[  5.65701874e-05], [  1.84972048e-03], [  8.46515331e-03], [  8.02505743e-02],
[  5.34274983e-04], [  5.18868535e-04], [  2.22580377e-04], [  2.50133462e-02],
[  3.70997917e-02], [  5.84941482e-05], [  6.49978323e-04], [  4.18675536e-01],
[  6.16371962e-02], [  3.82260752e-04], [  6.09901544e-04], [  2.54540201e-03],
[  2.46758824e-04], [  4.13621365e-04], [  5.23495532e-04], [  6.40675685e-03],
[  1.14165332e-03], [  1.89148994e-04], [  8.41715724e-04], [  8.65699032e-04],
[  6.71368283e-04], [  2.14908596e-03], [  5.80679210e-02], [  1.11176616e-02],
[  6.58134137e-05], [  2.38992622e-02], [  2.91388753e-04], [  1.93989753e-03],
[  1.82157325e-03], [  3.33691627e-03], [  5.69157244e-03], [  1.11033592e-04],
[  2.42448034e-04], [  8.42765356e-05], [  1.31656056e-02], [  1.68779684e-02],
[  2.72298244e-02], [  8.19056613e-04], [  1.14640462e-02], [  6.21846308e-05],
[  9.24618073e-04], [  3.63659515e-02], [  7.17286486e-05], [  6.24008652e-04],
[  2.59900890e-03], [  1.57848651e-04], [  5.71378707e-05], [  7.62828929e-04],
[  2.91648042e-04], [  1.67612579e-04], [  1.65455262e-04], [  1.01981563e-02]])
```

[image]

Some what of a Gaussian Distribution with a Skew to the Left. This Video by PoyserMath is excellent: [Stats: Finding Probability Using a Normal Distribution Table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZWd56VlN7w)  explaining why `p` must Sum to 1.0

**EDIT: 12.04.17** - Finally I found the python file that is associated with this!!!

```
# Author: Hamzeh Alsalhi <ha258@cornell.edu>
#
# License: BSD 3 clause
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
import operator
import array

from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
from sklearn.utils.fixes import astype
from ._random import sample_without_replacement

__all__ = ['sample_without_replacement', 'choice']


# This is a backport of np.random.choice from numpy 1.7
# The function can be removed when we bump the requirements to >=1.7
def choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None, random_state=None):
    """
    choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)

    Generates a random sample from a given 1-D array

    .. versionadded:: 1.7.0

    Parameters
    -----------
    a : 1-D array-like or int
        If an ndarray, a random sample is generated from its elements.
        If an int, the random sample is generated as if a was np.arange(n)

    size : int or tuple of ints, optional
        Output shape. Default is None, in which case a single value is
        returned.

    replace : boolean, optional
        Whether the sample is with or without replacement.

    p : 1-D array-like, optional
        The probabilities associated with each entry in a.
        If not given the sample assumes a uniform distribution over all
        entries in a.

    random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional (default=None)
        If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator;
        If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator;
        If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used
        by `np.random`.


    Returns
    --------
    samples : 1-D ndarray, shape (size,)
    The generated random samples

    Raises
    -------
    ValueError
    If a is an int and less than zero, if a or p are not 1-dimensional,
    if a is an array-like of size 0, if p is not a vector of
    probabilities, if a and p have different lengths, or if
    replace=False and the sample size is greater than the population
    size

    See Also
    ---------
    randint, shuffle, permutation

    Examples
    ---------
    Generate a uniform random sample from np.arange(5) of size 3:

    >>> np.random.choice(5, 3)  # doctest: +SKIP
    array([0, 3, 4])
    >>> #This is equivalent to np.random.randint(0,5,3)

    Generate a non-uniform random sample from np.arange(5) of size 3:

    >>> np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])  # doctest: +SKIP
    array([3, 3, 0])

    Generate a uniform random sample from np.arange(5) of size 3 without
    replacement:

    >>> np.random.choice(5, 3, replace=False)  # doctest: +SKIP
    array([3,1,0])
    >>> #This is equivalent to np.random.shuffle(np.arange(5))[:3]

    Generate a non-uniform random sample from np.arange(5) of size
    3 without replacement:

    >>> np.random.choice(5, 3, replace=False, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])
    ... # doctest: +SKIP
    array([2, 3, 0])

    Any of the above can be repeated with an arbitrary array-like
    instead of just integers. For instance:

    >>> aa_milne_arr = ['pooh', 'rabbit', 'piglet', 'Christopher']
    >>> np.random.choice(aa_milne_arr, 5, p=[0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3])
    ... # doctest: +SKIP
    array(['pooh', 'pooh', 'pooh', 'Christopher', 'piglet'],
    dtype='|S11')

    """
    random_state = check_random_state(random_state)

    # Format and Verify input
    a = np.array(a, copy=False)
    if a.ndim == 0:
        try:
            # __index__ must return an integer by python rules.
            pop_size = operator.index(a.item())
        except TypeError:
            raise ValueError("a must be 1-dimensional or an integer")
        if pop_size <= 0:
            raise ValueError("a must be greater than 0")
    elif a.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError("a must be 1-dimensional")
    else:
        pop_size = a.shape[0]
        if pop_size is 0:
            raise ValueError("a must be non-empty")

    if p is not None:
        p = np.array(p, dtype=np.double, ndmin=1, copy=False)
        if p.ndim != 1:
            raise ValueError("p must be 1-dimensional")
        if p.size != pop_size:
            raise ValueError("a and p must have same size")
        if np.any(p < 0):
            raise ValueError("probabilities are not non-negative")
        if not np.allclose(p.sum(), 1):
            raise ValueError("probabilities do not sum to 1")

    shape = size
    if shape is not None:
        size = np.prod(shape, dtype=np.intp)
    else:
        size = 1

    # Actual sampling
    if replace:
        if p is not None:
            cdf = p.cumsum()
            cdf /= cdf[-1]
            uniform_samples = random_state.random_sample(shape)
            idx = cdf.searchsorted(uniform_samples, side='right')
            # searchsorted returns a scalar
            idx = np.array(idx, copy=False)
        else:
            idx = random_state.randint(0, pop_size, size=shape)
    else:
        if size > pop_size:
            raise ValueError("Cannot take a larger sample than "
                             "population when 'replace=False'")

        if p is not None:
            if np.sum(p > 0) < size:
                raise ValueError("Fewer non-zero entries in p than size")
            n_uniq = 0
            p = p.copy()
            found = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.int)
            flat_found = found.ravel()
            while n_uniq < size:
                x = random_state.rand(size - n_uniq)
                if n_uniq > 0:
                    p[flat_found[0:n_uniq]] = 0
                cdf = np.cumsum(p)
                cdf /= cdf[-1]
                new = cdf.searchsorted(x, side='right')
                _, unique_indices = np.unique(new, return_index=True)
                unique_indices.sort()
                new = new.take(unique_indices)
                flat_found[n_uniq:n_uniq + new.size] = new
                n_uniq += new.size
            idx = found
        else:
            idx = random_state.permutation(pop_size)[:size]
            if shape is not None:
                idx.shape = shape

    if shape is None and isinstance(idx, np.ndarray):
        # In most cases a scalar will have been made an array
        idx = idx.item(0)

    # Use samples as indices for a if a is array-like
    if a.ndim == 0:
        return idx

    if shape is not None and idx.ndim == 0:
        # If size == () then the user requested a 0-d array as opposed to
        # a scalar object when size is None. However a[idx] is always a
        # scalar and not an array. So this makes sure the result is an
        # array, taking into account that np.array(item) may not work
        # for object arrays.
        res = np.empty((), dtype=a.dtype)
        res[()] = a[idx]
        return res

    return a[idx]


def random_choice_csc(n_samples, classes, class_probability=None,
                      random_state=None):
    """Generate a sparse random matrix given column class distributions

    Parameters
    ----------
    n_samples : int,
        Number of samples to draw in each column.

    classes : list of size n_outputs of arrays of size (n_classes,)
        List of classes for each column.

    class_probability : list of size n_outputs of arrays of size (n_classes,)
        Optional (default=None). Class distribution of each column. If None the
        uniform distribution is assumed.

    random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional (default=None)
        If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator;
        If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator;
        If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used
        by `np.random`.

    Returns
    -------
    random_matrix : sparse csc matrix of size (n_samples, n_outputs)

    """
    data = array.array('i')
    indices = array.array('i')
    indptr = array.array('i', [0])

    for j in range(len(classes)):
        classes[j] = np.asarray(classes[j])
        if classes[j].dtype.kind != 'i':
            raise ValueError("class dtype %s is not supported" %
                             classes[j].dtype)
        classes[j] = astype(classes[j], np.int64, copy=False)

        # use uniform distribution if no class_probability is given
        if class_probability is None:
            class_prob_j = np.empty(shape=classes[j].shape[0])
            class_prob_j.fill(1 / classes[j].shape[0])
        else:
            class_prob_j = np.asarray(class_probability[j])

        if np.sum(class_prob_j) != 1.0:
            raise ValueError("Probability array at index {0} does not sum to "
                             "one".format(j))

        if class_prob_j.shape[0] != classes[j].shape[0]:
            raise ValueError("classes[{0}] (length {1}) and "
                             "class_probability[{0}] (length {2}) have "
                             "different length.".format(j,
                                                        classes[j].shape[0],
                                                        class_prob_j.shape[0]))

        # If 0 is not present in the classes insert it with a probability 0.0
        if 0 not in classes[j]:
            classes[j] = np.insert(classes[j], 0, 0)
            class_prob_j = np.insert(class_prob_j, 0, 0.0)

        # If there are nonzero classes choose randomly using class_probability
        rng = check_random_state(random_state)
        if classes[j].shape[0] > 1:
            p_nonzero = 1 - class_prob_j[classes[j] == 0]
            nnz = int(n_samples * p_nonzero)
            ind_sample = sample_without_replacement(n_population=n_samples,
                                                    n_samples=nnz,
                                                    random_state=random_state)
            indices.extend(ind_sample)

            # Normalize probabilites for the nonzero elements
            classes_j_nonzero = classes[j] != 0
            class_probability_nz = class_prob_j[classes_j_nonzero]
            class_probability_nz_norm = (class_probability_nz /
                                         np.sum(class_probability_nz))
            classes_ind = np.searchsorted(class_probability_nz_norm.cumsum(),
                                          rng.rand(nnz))
            data.extend(classes[j][classes_j_nonzero][classes_ind])
        indptr.append(len(indices))

    return sp.csc_matrix((data, indices, indptr),
                         (n_samples, len(classes)),
                         dtype=int)
```

Comment: Did you try numpy for c#?! it's 4 times slower than python, but mostly the same. Just reference Numpy.dll via Nuget, set your build configuration to x64 and note that using string indexing in some cases like slicing. For example a[":,1" ] instead of a[:,1].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you want to randomly select X elements from a list of Y elements, according to distribution probability given by array of doubles, where each element represents probability of element with the same index being returned. The most straight forward way I can think of is this (see comments):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> _random = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());
static IEnumerable<T> Choice<T>(IList<T> sequence, int size, double[] distribution) {
    double sum = 0;
    // first change shape of your distribution probablity array
    // we need it to be cumulative, that is:
    // if you have [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4] 
    // we need     [0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1  ] instead
    var cumulative = distribution.Select(c => {
        var result = c + sum;
        sum += c;
        return result;
    }).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // now generate random double. It will always be in range from 0 to 1
        var r = _random.Value.NextDouble();
        // now find first index in our cumulative array that is greater or equal generated random value
        var idx = cumulative.BinarySearch(r);
        // if exact match is not found, List.BinarySearch will return index of the first items greater than passed value, but in specific form (negative)
        // we need to apply ~ to this negative value to get real index
        if (idx < 0)
            idx = ~idx; 
        if (idx > cumulative.Count - 1)
           idx = cumulative.Count - 1; // very rare case when probabilities do not sum to 1 becuase of double precision issues (so sum is 0.999943 and so on)
        // return item at given index
        yield return sequence[idx];
    }
}
```

I have hard time to explain this in plain words, but I think it should be relatively obvious from code. Maybe it's easiest to explain with example. Suppose we have distribution [0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1]. Cumulative version (when we add sum of all previous items to the current item) will look like this: [0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1]. Now we generate random number in range 0 to 1. It's distribution is uniform, so any value is equally likely. What's the probablity it will be in range 0-0.1? 0.1. And in range 0.1-0.5? 0.4. So you see that probability uniformely distributed 0-1 number will be in given range is exactly the same as we had in our probability distribution array.

Use like this:

```
var result = Choice(Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToArray(), 3, new double[] {0.01, 0.01, 0.48, 0.48, 0.02}).ToArray();
```

Will result in:

```
[3,3,3] // 
[2,3,2] // most often result with contain 2 and 3, because they both have 0.48 probablity and the rest elements have just 0.01
[1,3,2] // very rare other elements will appear
```

If you need version without repeats - it's also possible with slight modifications to this code.

If you need one item - call above function with `size = 1` or create overload for convenience. Same if you want to pass single integer instead of sequence:

```
static T Choice<T>(IList<T> sequence, double[] distribution) {
    return Choice(sequence, 1, distribution).First();
}

static int Choice(int upTo, double[] distribution) {
    return Choice(Enumerable.Range(0, upTo).ToArray(), distribution);
}
```

Comment: No, if you read Python's Numpy documentation, which is very average, then p is 'The probabilities associated with each entry in a' The function returns a single Choice, from a determined by p. E.G: x: 21 x[x]: 0.01314431 as shown above. x is the probability in a determined by p - But Thank You for this excellent effort!

Comment: Well if you look at last example at the link you provided, you will see that it can accept array of arbitrary items (like strings) and return sample of given size (5 in example). And I use the same meaning of `p` in my code. I you need one item - just pass size=1. Also passing single integer instead of array just means np.arange(n), so just passing array of integers up to that number. You can do the same with this code.

Comment: I've added some overloads which match different options from numpy random.choice.

Comment: Yes, but in practice, the line: x = np.random.choice(range(vocab_size), p=p.ravel()) - returns: <class 'numpy.int32'> - This is not as easy as one may think. How are you calculating the probability? I don't understand?

Comment: I tried to explain as I could in answer. I'd suggest you to try it out and see if you get the results you expect, and if you do - I'll try to explain better. So pass your 'a'   and your 'p', set size to 1 (though if you need multiple values - just call it with size you need instead of repeatedly calling in a loop) and see how it goes.

Comment: The Choice, Int Returned, is the chosen index of 'a' according to the Probability of the Distribution 'p'. This is not Random either, this is the confusing part! Its very accurate most of the time, according to the Distribution p.

Comment: It does not return index of 'a' - it returns element from a (according to probability yes), just like python version. Of course if you pass array of integers starting from 0 - index and element itself are the same.

Comment: The Code here shows a working example of what I mean: https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086

Comment: Please note: Parameters: `a : 1-D array-like or int - If an ndarray, a random sample is generated from its elements. If an int, the random sample is generated as if a was np.arange(n)` according to the Documentation.

Comment: I already added overload which accepts single int in the answer, and overload which accepts 1D array was always there. Please state exactly what is the problem. What you pass, what you expect, what goes wrong with the code provided, not just bunch of random python code like you did in previous comment. Did you actually try to run this code?

Comment: Apologies, I was attempting to clarify my comment. Nice Code by the way, putting it in place now, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to improve your code? its close but still very random. I see some structure, but it is not quite there.

Comment: 80% Error is best I can get, need to improve the 'find the highest probability'  - Isnt this a head full!

Comment: have finally found the Python Code associated with this Choice Call. Its a fairly complex file. Posted above.

Comment: This python code does _exactly_ the same thing I do in my code, uses absolutely the same algorithm (but has more error checks and has a code to handle sample without replaces) . You are talking about some mysterious "structure", 80% error, "highest probability", "it's still quite random" - I have no idea what you are talking about.  My code cannot be "improved" (only in terms of perfomance) - it either works or not. I won't waste any more time on this until you provide concrete example of what goes not as expected, without vague terms like "not quite there".

Comment: "It's quite random" is especially surprising. Sure it is random, but what else did you expect? If you want it to be not random - pass 1 for element you want and 0 for the rest (of course it makes no sense to do it, but if you don't like randomness...)

Comment: Ok, I see, I have gone through your Code, I understand your Code and I also understand the Python code. Its taken a bit of time for it to all sink in! Its not something I deal with a lot! So a lot of study, reading and a lot of catch up! Thank You! I agree, this is an excellent answer! Congratulations 50+ is yours!

Comment: I'm glad that we have a happy final here finally :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try NumSharp, a port of numpy to C#

```
double[] distribution = new double[] { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 };

//Simple choice
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
{
    int choice = NumSharp.np.random.choice(distribution.Count(), probabilities:distribution)[0].GetInt32();
    Console.Write(choice.ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

> 12222312301223333323323223022211111233123323333133211233333233013312213033030033

NumSharp includes aditionnal parameters (replace,...) but has still, to this date, performance issues:

```
EvalTime("NumSharp Single thread",() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        NumSharp.np.random.choice(distribution.Count(), probabilities: distribution)[0].GetInt32();
});

EvalTime("NumSharp Multithread", () =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, 100000, i => 
        NumSharp.np.random.choice(distribution.Count(), probabilities: distribution)[0].GetInt32());
});

EvalTime("Evk Single thread", () =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        Choice(upTo: distribution.Count(), distribution: distribution);
});

EvalTime("Evk Multithread", () =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, 100000, i =>
        Choice(upTo: distribution.Count(), distribution: distribution));
});

public static void EvalTime(string Name,Action a)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    a();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}ms", Name,sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Here's the output comparing NumSharp and Evk's implementation above on my PC (24 logical cores)

```
NumSharp Single thread : 10701ms
NumSharp Multithread : 19350ms
Evk Single thread : 117ms
Evk Multithread : 61ms
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please write a comment instead.

Comment: As an alternative to leaving a comment as @Machavity suggests, you could also edit your question to e.g., provide a code example using NumSharp to demonstrate how it solves the question.

Comment: Complaining the method is not implemented. I am using SciSharp.Tensorflow.Redist 2.4.1