# Select Random Items but with some items having a higher percentage of being selected?

Tags: c#, sql-server, random

I'm using MVC C# and SQL Sever.

I have about 100 items that I have been selecting 2 random items from.  This was straight forward sorting by a new guid.

```
 vm = vm.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2).ToList();
```

But now I want to be able to mark a subset of items to have a higher percentage (20%) of being selected  and then at a later date another subset to be 50%.

The list of items is static.  It will always be about 100 items.

I was just going to brute force it and add 20% more of the selected items to a list and them just do the random selection twice.

```
vm1 = vm.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).Single();
vm2 = vm.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid()).Where(_ => _.Id != firstSelectedID).Take(1).Single();
```

But was thinking there might be a cleaner more performant way in SQL or something that I'm missing in C#

Comment: Aside: [Don't use a Guid as a random number generator!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553). At least use `Random.Next()` instead.

Comment: This is not a random number generator.  Using Guid and Sort is random enough for this use case.  If I wanted true random I would look to use random.org

Comment: Well you are of course free to ignore [Eric Lippert's advice](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three/) when he says "*GUIDs are guaranteed to be unique but not guaranteed to be random. **Do not use them as random numbers.***"

Comment: Your items are in database or in memory? You want to do that with sql query or in memory is fine (will load all 100 items)?

Comment: Just imagine: Drawing a random element from (1,2,3) will have a 33,33% chance for each. With (1,2,3,3) you have 25% for (1,2) and 50% for 3

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree that they are not truly random but based on the dataset that I have which is now in the millions this is working fine and the distribution seems to be random enough for this use case.

Comment: @Evk Can be either.  At the moment I load the entries into a List and do a Linq call against it.  At the moment the data store is a json file to make access faster than DB.  But we do have a SQL backend for results and other storage.

Comment: You can check this answer for an example code of how to select element from array according to specific distribution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43345968/5311735

Comment: @userStack - There is nothing stopping the implementation of `Guid.NewGuid()` changing in the future so your code may work fine today, but in the next update guids might come out sequentially. You can't use guids for this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pure TSQL way of doing this, and you can write it the same way in C#, but I'm not sure how to do it through Entity Framework.

```
declare @table table ( letter nchar(1), weight int)
insert into @table values ('A', 1)
insert into @table values ('B', 2)
insert into @table values ('C', 3)
insert into @table values ('D', 4)
insert into @table values ('E', 5)

declare @total int;
select @total = sum(weight) from @table

declare @selected int;
set @selected = rand() * @total

select @selected

select top 1  * from (
select letter, weight, runningTotal = sum(weight) over (order by letter)
 from @table
) data where runningTotal > @selected order by runningTotal
```

You will get 'E' 5 tiles as often as it'll return 'A'.   This is roughly based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection   You can replace the weight column with any kind of process that'll give you a weighting.

You can run

```
select letter, weight, runningTotal = sum(weight) over (order by letter)
 from @table
```

And see how the data will be weighted.

Below version is better since it does it all in one operation, but I left the copy above in because it's more clear about what's going on.

```
select top 1  * from (
select letter, weight, runningTotal = sum(weight) over (order by letter)
 from @table
) data where runningTotal > rand() * (select sum(weight) from @table) order by runningTotal
```